# Getting network traffic of a remote IP?

Tags: networking

(Not sure if this is the right place to ask)

I want to get the network traffic and packets of an IP outside of my network from IP. For example, I can sniff my own network using Wireshark. Just like that, I want to "sniff" another IP's network. Is it even possible?

I want to find the public IP of a computer/server/network/etc. and get which packets they receive from whom.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: Questions about network you do not directly control, and questions about bypassing network security or policies are off-topic here. Network engineers will not help you hack their own networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question bluntly, no.

To "sniff" traffic to/from a destination you must be on the sending end, receiving end or somewhere along the path. If you were wanting to find out the IP's of servers you're connecting to then sure, Wireshark will work purely based on your network being the sender/receiver of said traffic.

For future reference, questions about networks out of your control are not permitted on this site.

Comment: @ditrapanji For example, I use Wireshark to sniff my network and find the IP of a server I am connected to. The question that I meant to ask was: Is it possible to get all connections that this server has? Am I considered "somewhere along the path"?

Comment: As in see who else is connected to the same server? Absolutely not without having control over that server/network. @Guest122444687511